# Using dplyr to summarise a running total of distinct factors

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct-values, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to generate a species saturation curve for a camera trapping survey. I have thousands of observations and do most of my manipulations in dplyr.

I have three field sites, with observation records of different animal species from a number of weeks of trapping. In some weeks there are no animals, in other weeks there may be more than one species. I want to generate a separate figure for each site to compare how quickly new species that are encountered over the sequential weeks of the study. These observations of new species should eventually saturate once the total species diversity has been captured in the area. Some field sites are likely to saturate faster than others.

The problem is that I have not come across a way of counting the number of distinct species to provide a running total by time. A simple dummy dataset is below.

```
field_site<-c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4),rep("C",4))
week<-c(1,2,2,3,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,4)
animal<-c("dog","dog","cat","rabbit","dog","dog","dog","rabbit","cat","cat","rabbit","dog")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(field_site,week,animal),head=TRUE)
```

I can easily generate the number of unique species within each week grouping, e.g.

```
tbl_df(df)%>%
  group_by(field_site,week) %>%
  summarise(no_of_sp=n_distinct(animal))
```

But this is not sensitive to the fact that some species are encountered again in subsequent weeks. What I really need is a running count of the different species that counts the unique species per site from week 1 going down through the rows, assuming that the data is sorted by increasing time from the start of the survey.

The cumulative total of species encountered over the course of the study by week in the example for field Site A would be: week 1 = 1 species, week 2 = 2 species, week 3 = 3 species, week 4 = still 3 species.

For site B cumulative total of species would be: week 1 = 0 species, week 2 = 1 species, week 3 = 1 species,week 4 = 1 species, etc...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
cheers in advance!

Comment: Isn't site B week 4 = 2 species, "dog" and "rabbit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making two assumptions:

1. Site B, week 4 = 2 species, both "dog" and "rabbit"; and
2. All sites share the same weeks, so if at least on site has week 4, then all sites should include it. This only drives the `mt` (empty) variable, feel free to update this variable.

I first suggest an "empty" data.frame to ensure sites have the requisite week numbers populated:

```
mt <- expand.grid(field_site = unique(ret$field_site),
                  week = unique(ret$week))
```

The use of `tidyr` helps:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(fake = TRUE) %>%
  # ensure all species are "represented" on each row
  spread(animal, fake) %>%
  # ensure all weeks are shown, even if no species
  full_join(mt, by = c("field_site", "week")) %>%
  # ensure the presence of a species persists at a site
  arrange(week) %>%
  group_by(field_site) %>%
  mutate_if(is.logical, funs(cummax(!is.na(.)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # helps to contain variable number of species columns in one place
  nest(-field_site, -week, .key = "species") %>%
  group_by(field_site, week) %>%
  # could also use purrr::map in place of sapply
  mutate(n = sapply(species, sum)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-species) %>%
  arrange(field_site, week)
# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    field_site   week     n
#        <fctr> <fctr> <int>
# 1           A      1     1
# 2           A      2     2
# 3           A      3     3
# 4           A      4     3
# 5           B      1     0
# 6           B      2     1
# 7           B      3     1
# 8           B      4     2
# 9           C      1     1
# 10          C      2     1
# 11          C      3     2
# 12          C      4     3
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for your very clear answer. Yes both of your above assumptions are correct, and everything makes sense. However, in applying this approach to my full dataset, I have run into a problem..  The observations of animals in the real study often turns up more than one per observation period (in this case weeks, but my data can also be organised into months and days). This creates a problem at the full_join stage of the approach to the expand.grid.  which returns "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),..." Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Can you update your sample data to reflect one such occurrence?

Comment: Sure thing @r2evans, here is an update of additional "dog" observations in week 2 at site A, and additional "rabbit" observations at week 3 of site B. field_site<-c(rep("A",5),rep("B",6),rep("C",4)) week<-c(1,2,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,4,1,2,3,4) animal<-c("dog","dog","dog","cat","rabbit","dog","dog","rabb‌​it","rabbit","dog","‌​rabbit","cat","cat",‌​"rabbit","dog") df<-as.data.frame(cbind(field_site,week,animal),head=TRUE) ## This produces the same error –

Comment: Try adding `distinct()` early in the pipeline.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If yes, please "accept" the answer.

Comment: Hi all, yes the suggestion did work, and many thanks to @r2evans for your help. The distinct() should go after the group_ by field for this example, and for my real data, I also had to filter out NA's (I can't paste the whole code as I do not have enough space).                               tbl_df(df) %>%
  filter(animal!="NA") %>%
  mutate(fake = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(field_site,week,animal,fake) %>%
  distinct()%>%